# Error adding appledoc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm adding appledoc, but I get an error:

```
line 3: /usr/local/bin/appledoc: No such file or directory
```

Thisline is --project-company "DEIMOS SPACE" \  I change the name for my company, but I'm not sure if this is correct, when can I see this name?

I add the script then I saw some tutorials like:  http://tutoriales-asg.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/configurar-appledoc-en-xcode.html   and http://www.simplicate.info/2013/07/25/using-appledoc-to-generate-xcode-help-part-1/
But this get error. How can do this correctly? What is bad?

Thanks!

Edit script is:

```
 /usr/local/bin/appledoc \
--project-name "${PROJECT_NAME}" \
--project-company "$YOUR_COMPANY" \  //Get /usr/local/bin/appledoc: No such file or directory HERE

--company-id "ExampleProject" \
--output "${PROJECT_DIR}/Help/${PROJECT_NAME}" \
--install-docset \
--logformat xcode \
-keep-undocumented-objects \
--keep-undocumented-members \
--keep-intermediate-files \
--no-repeat-first-par \
--no-warn-invalid-crossref \
--merge-categories \
--exit-threshold 2 \
--docset-platform-family iphoneos \
--ignore "*.m" \
--include "${PROJECT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Documentation/Images" \
--ignore "LoadableCategory.h" \
--index-desc "${PROJECT_DIR}/readme.markdown" \
"${PROJECT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the script you're using?

Comment: It just looks like you haven't installed `appledoc`. Have you? You have to install it before you try to use it.

Comment: Yes, I installed appledoc firstly like tutorial said. My script is added in question edit

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error. Type the 2 commands below.

```
$ brew install appledoc
Updating Homebrew...
$ ^C==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/appledoc-2.2.1.sierra.bottl
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring appledoc-2.2.1.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/appledoc/2.2.1: 26 files, 1.2M
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

> -keep-undocumented-objects \

have two dashes, like

> --keep-undocumented-objects \

?

Comment: But... I get error in --project-company "$YOUR_COMPANY" \ line

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you use a xcode target, the backslashes \ are not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Did you install *appledoc*? It is not part of OSX nor xcode; you need to install separately. Look at https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc and after cloning the repo, run the install script.

Comment: YES!, First I installed this. Download, and then install with terminal osX with sudo comand... All correctly.. But then in xcode get the error that I said

Answer (score 0):

Be sure appledoc is installed in the right path:

```
$ ls /usr/local/bin/appledoc
/usr/local/bin/appledoc
```

and try to run appledoc from the command line:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/appledoc
appledoc version: 2.1 (build 858)

ERROR: AppledocException: At least one directory or file name path is required, use 'appledoc --help'
```

Check that `$YOUR_COMPANY` is defined:

```
YOUR_COMPANY="DEIMOS"
```

or put your company name directly:

```
--project-company "DEIMOS" \
```

Be sure all flags have double dashes (--):

```
--keep-undocumented-objects \
```

Finally ensure all backslashes end the line, ie there is nothing behind them, not even a whitespace.

(copy-pasting your code above and making the changes accordingly works for me)